New installation of civicrm on Wordpress over old version
I have inherited a wordpress site that previously had civicrm installed (don't know the previous version).  The plugin directory and the civicrm tables were removed.  When I attempt to install (or "activate") the latest version, 5.77, from the wp-admin page, I get the following error:
Initialization Error:
Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => simpleHandler
        )

    [code] => -18
    [message] => DB Error: no such table
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE ((domain_id IS NULL OR domain_id = 1))
  AND (contact_id IS NULL)
 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'mydatabase.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE ((domain_id IS NULL OR domain_id = 1))
  AND (contact_id IS NULL)
 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'mydatabase.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such table" code=-18 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix="" info="SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE ((domain_id IS NULL OR domain_id = 1))
  AND (contact_id IS NULL)
 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'mydatabase.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]"]
)

...and wordpress crashes.  I never get to the page to configure the plugin.
Using a2hosting
Apache: 2.4.62
PHP: 7.4.33
mariadb: 8.0.37
It seems some configuration information from the previous installation is lurking somewhere, that civicrm (or wordpress) is trying to access, and I haven't been able to find it.  Can anyone give me an idea of where to look?


... the civicrm tables were removed

Can you explain more what this means? If you removed the tables, you'll need to put them back. The error is saying it can't find the tables.
Or if you mean you want to start a fresh install, you need to remove the civicrm.settings.php file and run the installer.

When civicrm was removed, the tables were removed from the database as well.  The fresh install is what I'm looking for...I'll remove the settings file and go from there.
